# "Please insert a valid JSON file." Showing in Kommunicate while integrating My dialogflow chatbot

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, chatbot, kommunicate

I am trying to integrate my Dialogflow chatbot to Kommunicate. But, when I am uploading provate key, it's failing.

I've generated the key json file by creating new service account under my project and then generating key in json format. I have also given "Owner" rights to account.

However  when I am uploading the key on Kommunicate platform, it's displaying "Please insert a valid JSON."

Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Also, do I have to change dialogflow's richmessages as per kommunicate's format or it can be integrated as it is?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you share the Dialogflow key file to us at support@kommunicate.io or contact us over email with your APP_ID and we will check it out.
No, changing Dialogflow rich messages is not required. Kommunicate supports both Dialogflow payload and we have our own payload as well. As we support multiple platforms that's why we have created our own payloads.